# Need help CSS class referring to markup-tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I'm working with Vaadin, a GWT like framework for developing rich web applications.

Now I want to set the padding of a generated HTML-tag element in my markup and I'm having big problems with it...

This is how the markup looks taken from Firebug:

[image]

The tags

- v-formlayout-captioncell
- v-formlayout-errorcell
- v-formlayout-contentcell

all have `padding-top: 12px` and `padding-bottom: 12px`, I would really like to change this padding to 2px, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've already tried these combinations among others:

```
.v-formlayout-captioncell td {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

---

```
v-formlayout-row td {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

---

```
.v-formlayout-row th,
.v-formlayout-row td {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

But none of them does any impact on the padding... could someone with better knowledge about CSS and HTML than me please take a look at this and give their opinion on how a CSS class should be written to do what I want. If you want me to provide more information then please ask! =)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Thank you [Taryn East](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219883/taryn-east) for your nice and graspable answer, it definitely taught me something new about CSS syntax! However, it seemed like the biggest problem I was having was that the padding parameters I was adding was overridden by the browser. But by using the `!important` CSS flag and writing the class as such it was fixed:

```
.v-formlayout-row td {
    padding-top: 2px !important;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

Comment: reading your comment in @Taryn answer I think it would help to create a demo of your problem at jsfiddle.net (copy your html and css there) to be able to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Sotiris! But the problem has been sorted as you can see in my edit. =)

Comment: if `!important` fix this, then there is a specificity problem. If you wish you can read more about it http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: I see what you mean. I read the article and I can definitely see how using !important can screw you over later in the development. I don't know how to specify the class correct though... it's way too wrapped inside different auto generated elements for me to make any sense of it. however, to avoid any problem I added a new class name to the html tag and refer to that in the style sheet. now there shouldn't be any mishaps in the future, I hope.. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class is in the td, then it should be:

```
td.v-formlayout-captioncell
```

the css here is saying is "find a td with the class 'v-formlayout-captioncell'"
By comparison, your css is saying: "find a td that is a descendant of something with the class 'v-formlayout-captioncell'"

**Edit:**

The reason why the `formatrow` isn't working is because CSS always picks the innermost style ie for

```
<tr class="a"><td class="b"></td></tr>
```

then anything in class b will override anything similar in class a.

In your case - the per-td padding was being set by an outside class, and you weren't overriding it with your 2px padding on the td... and any padding you were putting in the tr was simply being overridden by the outside-defined class on the td.

"important" fixes that because that gives it a priority to the tr styles that overrides the innermost-td style despite them being "more inner" - because they only have normal priority. However - this is kind of a bit of a hack that is unnecessary in your case.

The better-practise fix is just to use the `td.v-formlayout-captioncell` class

Comment: +1 thank you for your answer! however, I don't seem to get it to work... and with this reasoning that you presented here I assume that when I tried 'v-formlayout-row td' it really should have worked! But it doesn't! I can't seem to get it right... =(
don't see what the problem could be

Comment: The reason why the `formatrow` isn't working is because CSS always picks the innermost style ie if you have `<tr class="a"><td class="b"></td></tr>` then anything on class b will override anything similar in class a.